# How to stop MooTools stripping element IDs when clicked in Joomla 2.5.x using the 'modal' class

Tags: class, plugins, joomla, mootools, modal-dialog

I am using Joomlaworks Simple Image Gallery Pro plugin and I want to open the Galleria layout in a modal window and I am at a point where it opens fine using Joomla's 'modal' class but it appears Mootools strips all IDs from the elements in the window when popped so any thumbnail clicked, opens the image in a new window instead of the Galleria container because the IDs are not available for communication with the javascript.

What function needs to be added for Mootools to keep the element IDs?

This is my configuration

```
<style>#hidden {display:none;}</style>

<a class="modal" href="#hidden" rel="{size: {x: 800, y: 700}}">Show Gallery </a>

<div id="hidden">
{gallery}jane:74:50:0:2::Galleria{/gallery}
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a live link? or can you make it to a jsfiddle?